# Can't get checkpoint to load in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'd like for the latest checkpoint to be loaded in Flink but it just isn't. I've written a word count application that is meant to resume counting where it left off after a restart. I am running it from my IDE so I'm not starting a Flink cluster.

Here's the code I wrote https://github.com/edu05/wordcount/tree/simple
Which is inspired from the example provided by the Flink creators on checkpointing... https://github.com/streaming-with-flink/examples-scala

What am I missing? How can I also avoid re-printing some of the word counts? I don't see many contributors in Stackoverflow on Apache Flink, is there another more appropriate forum?

Comment: Are you getting some error ? Can you show us how did you try to run from a checkpoint ?

Comment: I can't see any error but when I start up the app the word counts start from zero. I am not taking any special actions to run from a checkpoint, I thought this happened automatically. I'm just running the main() method from my IDE, waiting to see the word counts going up, waiting for a couple of checkpoints to be produced (I only ascertained this from the logs); I then stop the app from the IDE and then I rerun the same main() method again from my IDE. My expectation was for the app to resume with the previous word counts. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Checkpoints are by default not retained and are only used to resume a job from failures.

If you need to start your job from a retained checkpoint you have to do it manually just as from savepoint by the following way:

```sh
$ bin/flink run -s :checkpointMetaDataPath [:runArgs]
```

Comment: What constitutes a failure? I'd like to use Flink in a production environment but I need to be able to demonstrate correct behaviour under certain circumstances. In my working environment we would not like to have to take any manual action due to a restart of some machines (hardware updates happen occasionally) and we wouldn't view restarts as a failure but rather as a pause in service from which we need to be able to resume. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: It's hard to describe all the failures, guarantees and how it behaves in failure circumstances. Some failures are: machine hardware and network.
Some failures and behaviours are described in the following links: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/internals/stream_checkpointing.html
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/connectors/guarantees.html

Comment: Ok but I suspect in any viable production environment you'd like to minimise the number of circumstances that require human intervention for recovery. I wouldn't want someone to have to connect to a deployment box, handpick a checkpoint and start running commands on the console but for the dearest of circumstances. Regardless of the recovery mechanism (i.e. I'm open to the idea of using mechanisms other than checkpoints) there must be a way to reload state (from a database, checkpoint, Kafka topic, I'm open to suggestions) after a restart.

Comment: By default, a fixed delay restart strategy is chosen if there is no other restart strategy defined. The fixed delay restart strategy attempts a given number of times to restart the job. If the maximum number of attempts is exceeded, the job eventually fails. You can see more information about restart strategies in the following link: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/restart_strategies.html#fixed-delay-restart-strategy